# Duplicate rows based on value with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I need to replicate some rows in a panda data frame like this

```
name  times
   A      2
   B      1
   C      3
   D     20
...
```

What I need is to replicate rows just when col2 value is less than 20

What I'm doing now is:

```
for t in df["times"]:
       if t < 20:
           df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(t)]
```

But the script keeps running and I have to stop it (I've been waiting a long time...).

Is there any way to improve this or doing it in another way?

Comment: @Viskovitz I had some problem understanding your need. Do we assume well that you want to repeat row as many times as the value in 'times'? E.g. repeat 'C' three times, not twice?

Comment: I need to obtain as many identical rows as the initial value of times column. If 'C' have 3 in times column, the final dataframe must have 'C' tree times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
#condition lt for <
mask = df['times'].lt(20)
#filter by boolean indexing
df1 = df[mask].copy()
#repeat rows
df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(df1['times'])]

#add rows higher like 20, sorting and create default index
df = pd.concat([df1, df[~mask]]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  name  times
0    A      2
1    A      2
2    B      1
3    C      3
4    C      3
5    C      3
6    D     20
```